# how to run a spider in Scrapy several times with changing a part of url in "def start_requests(self)"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a question about the logic of this spider. I want to crawl one of the categories of the Castbox website which has infinite pagination.
So, I thought that I can split the URL of the JSON file, then slice, and at last, re-join the URL to be able to parse it. Therefore, I used a while loop to determine a condition under which my spider continues crawling the elements I need.

let me explain it clearly.

when I checked the JSON URL of the Castbox website, I recognized that only one part of the URL changes every time it is reloaded by scrolling down the page. This part is called "skip" which changes between 0 to 200 and you'll see it in the URL. So, I thought that if I can write a "def start_requests(self)" in which URL's "skip" part can changes from 0 to 200, I can get what I want.
Is such functionality possible to change the URL every time? If yes, what is wrong with the "def start_requests(self)" part of my spider?

By the way, when running it, I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Here is my spider:

```
-- coding: utf-8 --
import scrapy
import json

class ArtsPodcastsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'arts_podcasts'
    allowed_domains = ['www.castbox.fm']
    

    def start_requests(self):
        
        try:
            if response.request.meta['skip']:
                skip=response.request.meta['skip']
            else:
                skip=0
                
            while skip < 201:
                url = 'https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=0&limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1'
                split_url = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
                path = split_url.path
                path.split('&')
                path.split('&')[:-5]
                '&'.join(path.split('&')[:-5])
                parsed_query = urlparse.parse_qs(split_url.query)
                query = urlparse.parse_qs(split_url.query, keep_blank_values=True)
                query['skip'] = skip
                updated = split_url._replace(path='&'.join(base_path.split('&')[:-5]+['limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1', '']),
                    query=urllib.urlencode(query, doseq=True))
                updated_url=urlparse.urlunsplit(updated)
                
                
                yield scrapy.Request(url= updated_url, callback= self.parse_id, meta={'skip':skip})
    
                def parse_id(self, response):

                    skip=response.request.meta['skip']
                    data=json.loads(response.body)
                    category=data.get('data').get('category').get('name')
                    arts_podcasts=data.get('data').get('list')
                    for arts_podcast in arts_podcasts:
                        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip={0}&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1'.format(arts_podcast.get('list')[2].get('cid')), meta={'category':category,'skip':skip}, callback= self.parse)


                def parse(self, response):

                    skip=response.request.meta['skip']
                    category=response.request.meta['category']
                    arts_podcast=json.loads(response.body).get('data')
                    yield scrapy.Request(callback=self.start_requests,meta={'skip':skip+1})
                    yield{

                        'title':arts_podcast.get('title'),
                        'category':arts_podcast.get('category'),
                        'sub_category':arts_podcast.get('categories'),
                        'subscribers':arts_podcast.get('sub_count'),
                        'plays':arts_podcast.get('play_count'),
                        'comments':arts_podcast.get('comment_count'),
                        'episodes':arts_podcast.get('episode_count'),
                        'website':arts_podcast.get('website'),
                        'author':arts_podcast.get('author'),
                        'description':arts_podcast.get('description'),
                        'language':arts_podcast.get('language')
                        }
```

Thank you!

---EDIT---

This a part of the log I got after running the spider, @Patrick Klein:

```
2020-11-14 15:51:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=0&limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1> (referer: None)
2020-11-14 15:51:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=0&limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\shima\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\shima\projects\castbox_arts_podcasts\castbox_arts_podcasts\spiders\arts_podcasts.py", line 27, in parse_id
    url = f'https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip={arts_podcast.get("list")[2].get("cid")}&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

---EDIT 2---

```
2020-11-15 13:14:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=2583691&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1> (referer: https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=8&limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1)
2020-11-15 13:14:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=2946683&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1>
{'sub_category': None, 'title': None, 'subscribers': None, 'plays': None, 'comments': None, 'episodes': None, 'downloads': None, 'website': None, 'author': None, 'description': None, 'language': None}
2020-11-15 13:14:47 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGINT twice, forcing unclean shutdown
2020-11-15 13:14:47 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11] WARNING: Got data loss in https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=12&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1. If you want to process broken responses set the setting DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS = False -- This message won't be shown in further requests
2020-11-15 13:14:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip=12&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>, <twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.web.http._DataLoss: Chunked decoder in 'CHUNK_LENGTH' state, still expecting more data to get to 'FINISHED' state.>]
```

A part of the JSON object for one item desired to be scraped:

```
{
    "msg": "OK",
    "code": 0,
    "data": {
        "category": {
            "sub_categories": [
                {
                    "image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "id": "10022",
                    "night_image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "name": "Books"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "id": "10023",
                    "night_image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "name": "Design"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "id": "10024",
                    "night_image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "name": "Fashion & Beauty"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "id": "10025",
                    "night_image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "name": "Food"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "id": "10026",
                    "night_image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "name": "Performing Arts"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "id": "10027",
                    "night_image_url": "https://castbox.fm/static/everest/category/v3/grey/default.png",
                    "name": "Visual Arts"
                }
            ],
            "id": "10021",
            "name": "Arts"
        },
        "list": [
            {
                "provider_id": 125443881,
                "episode_count": 256,
                "x_play_base": 0,
                "stat_cover_ext_color": false,
                "keywords": [
                    "Arts",
                    "Literature",
                    "TV & Film",
                    "Society & Culture",
                    "freshair",
                    "npr",
                    "terrygross",
                    "news",
                    "facts",
                    "interesting",
                    "worldwide",
                    "international",
                    "best",
                    "awardwinning",
                    "jay z"
                ],
                "cover_ext_color": "-8610134",
                "mongo_id": "5e74365585a4e5dcff18d769",
                "show_id": "56a0a3399eb9a8dd9758c9c2",
                "copyright": "Copyright 2015-2019 NPR - For Personal Use Only",
                "author": "NPR",
                "is_key_channel": true,
                "audiobook_categories": [],
                "comment_count": 29,
                "website": "http://www.npr.org/programs/fresh-air/",
                "rss_url": "https://feeds.npr.org/381444908/podcast.xml",
                "description": "Fresh Air from WHYY, the Peabody Award-winning weekday magazine of contemporary arts and issues, is one of public radio's most popular programs. Hosted by Terry Gross, the show features intimate conversations with today's biggest luminaries.",
                "tags": [
                    "from-itunes"
                ],
                "editable": true,
                "play_count": 8890966,
                "link": "http://www.npr.org/programs/fresh-air/",
                "twitter_names": [
                    "nprfreshair"
                ],
                "categories": [
                    10021,
                    10022,
                    10125,
                    10001,
                    10101,
                    10014,
                    10015
                ],
                "x_subs_base": 25254,
                "small_cover_url": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts113/v4/76/32/0c/76320cb7-7805-5ffc-6d48-18b311dd9be8/mza_18321298089187816075.jpg/200x200bb.jpg",
                "big_cover_url": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts113/v4/76/32/0c/76320cb7-7805-5ffc-6d48-18b311dd9be8/mza_18321298089187816075.jpg/600x600bb.jpg",
                "language": "en",
                "cid": 2698788,
                "latest_eid": 326888897,
                "topic_tags": [
                    "FreshAir",
                    "NPR"
                ],
                "release_date": "2020-11-14T05:01:15Z",
                "title": "Fresh Air",
                "uri": "/ch/2698788",
                "https_cover_url": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Podcasts113/v4/76/32/0c/76320cb7-7805-5ffc-6d48-18b311dd9be8/mza_18321298089187816075.jpg/400x400bb.jpg",
                "channel_type": "private",
                "channel_id": "47b5be27cc1ca68aa80f8f7bbccedb47a40992d3",
                "sub_count": 361101,
                "internal_product_id": "cb.ch.2698788",
                "social": {
                    "website": "http://www.npr.org/programs/fresh-air/",
                    "youtube": [
                        {
                            "name": "channel/UCwly5-E5e0EUY-SsnttN4Sg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "twitter": [
                        {
                            "name": "nprfreshair"
                        }
                    ],
                    "facebook": [
                        {
                            "name": "freshairwithterrygross"
                        }
                    ],
                    "instagram": [
                        {
                            "name": "nprfreshair"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're trying to access meta of `response.request` in start_requests. However, in start_requests you haven't made a request yet, so there is no response. Meaning your function will already throw an exception in the first if. Also, there is no except block, so your linter should already show you a warning or an error. Another thing is that you're defining your methods in your while loop. Is this intentional? If not, you should fix the indentation in your question.

Comment: If necessary, you should use [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs) (= callback keyword arguments) instead of using meta. 
`meta` is better used to pass data to middlewares and pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that you're passing `category` and `skip` to your parse functions, but don't really use them in your spider. There were actually a lot of unused and possibly not necessary imports.
Also, you used almost the same URL in your `parse_id` as in your `start_requests` method.

I've rewritten your spider to something that I think somewhat resembles what you want to achieve a little differently.

```
import scrapy
import json

class ArtsPodcastsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'arts_podcasts'

    def start_requests(self):
        for skip in range(201):
            url = f'https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip={skip}&limit=60&web=1&m=20201112&n=609584ea96edb64605bca96212128aa5&r=1'
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, 
                callback=self.parse_id, 
            )

    def parse_id(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        arts_podcasts = data.get('data').get('list')
        for arts_podcast in arts_podcasts:
            url = f'https://everest.castbox.fm/data/top_channels/v2?category_id=10021&country=us&skip={arts_podcast["cid"]}&limit=60&web=1&m=20201111&n=609ba0097bb48d4b0778a927bdcf69f4&r=1'
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url, 
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        arts_podcasts=json.loads(response.body).get('data')
        for arts_podcast in arts_podcasts['list']:
            yield {
                'title':arts_podcast.get('title'),
                'category':arts_podcast.get('category'),
                'sub_category':arts_podcast.get('categories'),
                'subscribers':arts_podcast.get('sub_count'),
                'plays':arts_podcast.get('play_count'),
                'comments':arts_podcast.get('comment_count'),
                'episodes':arts_podcast.get('episode_count'),
                'website':arts_podcast.get('website'),
                'author':arts_podcast.get('author'),
                'description':arts_podcast.get('description'),
                'language':arts_podcast.get('language')
            }
```

Comment: @Ptrick Klein, thank you so much!!! It is running without a problem but the thing is, the .csv output is empty. And the .XML output cannot be opened in excel. Although, I don't get any error while running the spider. Do you know if this is related to this question or I have to ask it in another one? If not, can you tell me please, why this problem happened?

Comment: I edited the post above to show you the log I got if it helps. @Patrick Klein

Comment: The log looks like there's an error in `parse_id`, more specifically the part `arts_podcast.get("list")[2].get("cid")`. I suspect, that either the value for arts_podcast is none or there is no "list".  If I understand this correctly, the following should work: `arts_podcast.get("cid")`

Comment: Thank you, @Patrick Klein. I tried a lot to solve this problem myself but I couldn't. You were right! I can now open the output. But the problem is that all the items are shown as "None" although they shouldn't be. So, I guess I am addressing the items wrongly inside the yield part, but I cannot find the solution. So, I edited the post again and put the log and a part of the JSON object there.

Comment: You're welcome! That makes sense. The response you get in `parse` also contains a list, so you'll need to iterate over that as well. I've updated my answer accordingly. Still, the requests yielded in `start_requests` as well as in `parse_id` are pretty much the same, so I suspect there is still a logical flaw. To me it looks like `parse_id` is either unnecessary or you wanted to modify the category_id parameter of the url instead of the skip parameter